# Poetry scripts ModuleOrPackageNotFound error for tool.poetry.scripts

Tags: python-poetry

I was trying to create build and run scripts using

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
start = "scripts:start"
```

in the pyproject.toml file, but encountered this exception

```
ModuleOrPackageNotFound
No file/folder found for package my-package
....
```

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve this problem after some hair-pulling

Firstly: make sure that your directory structure is what poetry expects, i.e.
A directory on the same level as pyproject.toml with the same name as the your package root directory (my_package/my_package)

```
my_package
├── my_package
│   ├── __init__.py
|   └── scripts.py
└── pyproject.toml
```

Secondly, and this was my issue, ensure that the **directory names use underscores ( _ ), not hyphens ( - )**, as poetry resolves the directory name to use underscores instead of hyphens, as defined in PEP-8.

Answer (score 0):

More specific you have to use the same "name" in you pyproject.toml as the folder name in which my_script.py is located:

[tool.poetry]
name = "my_package"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
my_script = "my_package.my_script:start"